# Determining whether Ellipse2D is overlapping with Rectangle

Tags: java, overlap

Hello guys I would like to ask how to determine whether my Ellipse2D contains a Rectangle
Let's say I got rectangle as a player hitbox

```
playerHitBox = new Rectangle(x+36,y+16,51,107);
```

and for the enemy sight I've got an ellipse named sight

```
Ellipse2D sight = new Ellipse2D.Double(x,y,500,500);
```

what is the best way to determine whether these two are overlapping
because if I use sight.contains(playerHitBox) seems like the whole rectangle has to be inside of the enemy sight

Comment: Try [`Shape#intersects`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/geom/RectangularShape.html#intersects(java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D)) instead

Comment: Didnt expect it to be that simple thx man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use shape.intersects();